# how can I align colons in ternary operator?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want my code to align like this

```
double flagx_ul = wx * 2 > wy *3 ? -wy * 3 / 2 / wx : -1.0;
double flagy_ul = wx * 2 > wy *3 ? 1.0              : wx * 2 / 3 / wy;
double flagx_lr = wx * 2 > wy *3 ? wy * 3 / 2 / wx  : 1.0;
double flagy_lr = wx * 2 > wy *3 ? -1.0             : -wx * 2 / 3 / wy;
```

all I found in clangformat documents is

```
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators (Boolean) clang-format 3.7
If true, ternary operators will be placed after line breaks.

true:
veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongDescription
    ? firstValue
    : SecondValueVeryVeryVeryVeryLong;

false:
veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongDescription ?
    firstValue :
    SecondValueVeryVeryVeryVeryLong;
```

How can I keep them in a line, but align **?** and **:**

Answer (score 1):

Readability is usably increased by making functions, even for short statements.
And in this case it can also help you reduce code duplication.
Here's an example :

```
bool fn(const double a, const double b)
{
    return (a / b) * (3.0 / 2.0);
}

int main()
{
    double wx = 1.0;
    double wy = 2.0;

    // only do your predicate calculation once.
    auto pred = ((wx * 2.0) > (wy * 3.0));

    // and by using ! you can align the most similar parts of the ternary operation.
    double flagx_ul =  pred ? fn(-wy,wx) : -1.0;  
    double flagy_ul = !pred ? fn( wx,wy) :  1.0;
    double flagx_lr =  pred ? fn( wy,wx) :  1.0;
    double flagy_lr = !pred ? fn(-wx,wy) : -1.0;
}
```

Comment: I get your point, but in this case, I just want to know how to align colons so that I can quickly figure out **flagx and flagy**. If the code is worth others reading, I surly will do as you say.